# React parent function doesn't receive child parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a strange problem.

I created my function copy in my parent component.

```
const copy = (field, menu) => {
    console.log({ field, menu, localMetaSpec });

    localMetaSpec.menus[menu.id].elements.splice(
        localMetaSpec.menus[menu.id].elements.length,
        0,
      { ...field, id: uuid() }
    );
    return localMetaSpec;
};
```

Then I gave it to my child component, and I called it like this

```
[...]
case 'copy':
     return (
         <Tooltip title='Copy'>
             <IconButton
               aria-label='copy'
               onClick={() => {
                 console.log(field);
                 console.log(menu);
                 actions.copy(field, menu);
               }}
             >
             <FileCopyIcon />
         </IconButton>
     </Tooltip>
    );
[...]
```

As you can see in the console, **field** and **menu** are *objects*, but when received as a parameter in the function they become *undefined*.
[image]

Why this is happening?

Comment: What is the meaning of actions.copy because you can directly pass under copy(field, menu),

Comment: Because I'm passing several functions to my child component, so I pass it through actions that contain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was from the parent component where I called the child one :

```
<Menu
  actions={{
    copy: () => copy(),
    delete: () => deleteElement(),
  }}
  classes={classes}
  elements={elements}
  key={menu.id}
  menu={menu}
/>
```

I wasn't passing the parameter through the original function.
So I did that :

```
<Menu
  actions={{
    copy: (fieldParam, menuParam) => copy(fieldParam, menuParam),
    delete: () => deleteElement(),
  }}
  classes={classes}
  elements={elements}
  key={menu.id}
  menu={menu}
/>
```